# Google Maps V3 how to find center cords?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple question I am sure for some but I haven't been able to find anything.

Is there some piece of small code I can put in my map that will show the center cords of the pan when I drag the map around? I am just needing this so I can get the cords and hard code it so it is centered exactly where I want it so it will open in the same place where I want it each time. I don't know how else to find the center cords other then just trial and error trying different cords but that would be tedious. So if there is a easier way to display what the center of the map is when you are dragging it around that would be great.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the center coordinates: `map.getCenter()`

Hope this helps!!!!

Comment: Thanks! I searched how to use that and came back with this example. http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/google_maps_api_v3/en/map_example_21.html and I tried that but it's not working so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The link to my code is here. http://www.mesquiteweather.net/wxsvr.php

Comment: All sorted I used the suggestion above and found an example <button onclick="alert(map.getCenter());">Get center</button>
<br><br> that worked!

Comment: You can also see the result using the above command in the browser console.

Comment: I am not familiar with the browser console. Could you explain what that is so I know for future reference?

Comment: I suggest you use Firefox and the Firebug console https://getfirebug.com/ then you can use `console.log(someVariable);` or `console.dir(someArray);` instead of using alerts. Hope this helps.